# Character controller passes through mesh collider

Tags: unity, collision-detection, game-design

I need a little help figuring out what's going on with an NPC's character controller. Here are the character controller settings for the NPC.

[image: character controller settings]
The problem I'm running into is that the NPC isn't walking up a slight gradient as it should; instead, it moves **through** the ground.

Below are the settings for the ground.

[image: ground mesh settings]

The NPC isn't on the ground- it is a few units off. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have a collider and a rigidbody controller on your player? Do you have a rigidbody collider on your terrain?

Comment: Yes, the 1st image is the NPC's character controller which has similar settings to the player's character controller. I tried using a rigidBody for the NPC but it was still doing the same thing.

The image below is the the ground's mesh collider. Just to test, I added a kinematic rigidBody to the ground & the NPC is still behaving the same way.

Comment: Are you sure that both colliders fit exactly to the shape of the objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a raycast or this script.
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/groundnpc.181705/#post-1241872

Don't add a `Rigidbody` if you use the controller. It breaks it big time.

And check off convex on the mesh collider for your terrain. Try this first before adding a script. I remember having this problem before and that's all it took.

Comment: I updated & used the script from the link you posted. It works brilliantly! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an update to a script found [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/groundnpc.181705/#post-1241872):

This is a simple fix that prevents NPCs from walking through sloped mesh.

```
#pragma strict

var gravity = 20.0;
var verticalSpeed= 0.0;
private var collisionFlags : CollisionFlags;  // The last collision flags returned from 
                                              // controller.Move

function Update() 
{   
    ApplyGravity();

    // Calculate actual motion
    var movement = Vector3 (0, verticalSpeed, 0) + Vector3.zero;
    movement *= Time.deltaTime;

    // Move the controller
    var controller : CharacterController = GetComponent.<CharacterController>();
    collisionFlags = controller.Move(movement);
}

function ApplyGravity()
{
    verticalSpeed = IsGrounded() ? 0.0 : verticalSpeed - gravity * Time.deltaTime
}

function IsGrounded()
{
    var controller : CharacterController = GetComponent.<CharacterController>();
    return (controller.collisionFlags == CollisionFlags.Below);
}
```